# Modifying arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I apologize for the excessive length, I just wanted to make sure I actually understand what's going on here. This is a follow up on my previous two questions [Does 'upcase!' not mutate a variable in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625180/does-upcase-not-mutate-a-variable-in-ruby) and [Destructive and non destructive methods in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718857/destructive-and-non-destructive-methods-in-ruby).

```
def changeMe(string) 
  string + "?"
end

phrase = "how are you"
puts changeMe(phrase) #how are you?
puts phrase #how are you
```

When `changeMe` is invoked with the `phrase` passed in as an argument, the parameter `string` points to the same object as `phrase`. When we change the line to `string + "?"` we are creating a new object different from the one the string parameter points to, the same if we assigned the newly created object to a variable.

```
def changeMe(string) 
  string += "?"
end
phrase = "how are you"
puts changeMe(phrase) #how are you?
puts phrase #how are you
```

If I do this -

```
def changeMe(string) 
  string + "?"
  string.capitalize!
end
phrase = "how are you"
puts changeMe(phrase) #How are you
puts phrase #How are you
```

When `changeMe` is invoked with `phrase` passed in as an argument,  the `string + "?"` creates a new object different from the one `#capitalize!` is called on in the next line. `#capitalize!` is called on the object that the variable `phrase` is referencing, the same object the string parameter points to but not the same object returned by `string + ?`.  If we reassign it to a variable,

```
def changeMe(string) 
  string += "?"
  string.capitalize!
end
phrase = "how are you"
puts changeMe(phrase) #How are you?
puts phrase #how are you
```

`string += "?"` will create a new object that is assigned to a variable called `string`. That new object has `#capitalize!` called on it. The method is invoked with `phrase` passed in as an argument and returns a new object different from the one the variable `phrase` references so the original value for the variable `phrase` is unchanged.

Are there flaws or misconceptions in my logic. Am I accurately explaining/understanding things?

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Said a different way, In Ruby, variables and method names are snake_case, not camelCase. ItIsA readability_thing.

Comment: Your understanding is perfect now. That's all you need to know!

Answer (score 4):

That's largely correct, but perhaps a more complicated path to understanding than necessary. In Ruby one thing that helps a lot is calling `object_id` on a given object to see *which* object it is. Every object has a unique `object_id`.

For example:

```
"test" == ("te" + "st")
# => true
"test".object_id == ("te" + "st").object_id
# => false
```

Or more specifically for a method that creates a new copy:

```
x = 'test'
y = x + '?'

x.object_id == y.object_id
# => false
```

You can see how in-place modifications work:

```
x = 'test'
y = x << '?'

x.object_id == y.object_id
# => true
```

Where this allows you to differentiate between in-place modifications and methods that produce new objects or copies.

Remember that *every* Ruby expression returns an object. If this object is  not captured into a variable or used as an argument will often can be discarded if not already used.

In other words there's a huge difference between this:

```
def add
  1 + 2   # Computed and discarded
  :three  # The actual return value
end
```

And this:

```
def add
  1 + 2   # Computed and returned
end
```

Though this depends on that return value being captured, as calling the function computes the value and throws out the results again *unless* it's captured or used.